# DLL Load Failed: The specified module could not be found [Python]

Tags: python, dll, scikit-learn, anaconda, conda

Not sure what the issue is...

...but many of the classifiers will not work on my machine now.

I just installed version 14.1 of scikit-learn. Could this be a path thing?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hashtag.py", line 19, in <module>
    from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.14.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\sk
learn\linear_model\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .logistic import LogisticRegression
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.14.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\sk
learn\linear_model\logistic.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..svm.base import BaseLibLinear
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.14.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\sk
learn\svm\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.14.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\sk
learn\svm\classes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import BaseLibLinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.14.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\sk
learn\svm\base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import libsvm, liblinear
**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**

C:\Users\Owner>
```

Thank you in advance with your help.

Comment: How did you install it? Using the `conda install`? Or building it from the source?

Comment: I installed it through Conda.

Comment: Which version of Anaconda have you installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a bug in the conda recipe / package. You can try to update conda and anaconda with:

```
conda update conda  # update the updater :)
conda update anaconda
```

If that does not work fix the issue, you can also try:

```
conda remove scikit-learn
conda install scikit-learn
```

Comment: `conda install -f scikit-learn` will force reinstall scikit-learn.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this with

```
pip install scipy -U
```