# Can't import sklearn on Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm trying to import the skit-learn library but it´s generate this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 144, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: DLL load failed: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
```

Someone could say what's happening, I'm completely lost with this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide as much detail as possible. How did you install sklearn?

Comment: I just follow the instruction on: [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this seems obvious but there's not a lot of information given here so i can't tell what you already tried or not.

This package isn't included in the standard library so you'd have to have downloaded/installed it before importing did you follow the instructions on the library's website? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

Edit: found a similar issue [DLL Load Failed: The specified module could not be found [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308451/dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-python)

Comment: Yes I did! First I install NumPy and SciPy, and so I installed Scikit using the comand show in website: _pip install -U scikit-learn_

Comment: instead of using the pip command you can follow that similar post's answer (force installing with conda)

Comment: To use this I have to install Anaconda, right? Scikit do not work with Python?

Comment: Is it possible to run without install anaconda?

Comment: I don't know if it would work without but a lot of answers on SO for similar problems seem to revolve around installing anaconda. I'm not  experienced with python package managers so I'm afraid i can't help you further.

Comment: @Pinhal you do not have to install Anaconda just for Scikit learn (you could if you want to, it’s simpler). Anaconda is just a complete package for data science that has lots of these libraries pre-installed. It’s possible that you just need to do reinstall it using `pip uninstall scikit-learn` and `pip install scikit-learn` And you might as well also check if `import numpy, scipy` works.

Comment: @Pinhal Anaconda is a *Python distribution*. Of *course* scikit-learn works with Python, it is a Python library. However, especially on windows, it is hard to distribute Python packages that have complex dependencies. `scikit-learn` depends on `numpy`, which requires compiled C binaries, BLAS / LAPACK linear algebra wrappers, and a even a fortran compiler, I believe. The headaches this caused on windows lead to the development of `conda` which is the *package manger* that comes with the `Anaconda` distribution.

Comment: @Pinhal so, *especially* if you are new, it is recommended to just use `Anaconda` on Windows. Personally, I would uninstall your current Python interpreter, and get Anaconda and just stick to that. Always try to install libraries with `conda` first. If `conda` doesn't have the library, then try `pip`, but `conda` should have all the "pydata stack", e.g. `numpy`, `scipy`, `sklearn`, `matplotlib`, etc, etc Anyway, if you get the full Anaconda distribution, it will come with all those libraries already.

Comment: @abccd I already uninstall and install scikit, and even install na older version of scipy but didn't work. NumPy and SciPy I can import normally, only the scilit library isn't working.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga to install Anaconda I have to uninstall Python?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  So, if it's like you said, scikit-learn don't work in Python running on Windows, because if I did every installation right it should work, or not? I just want to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Pinhal Anaconda *is Python*, it is a Python distribution which includes the scipy-stack along with the standard library. But yes, uninstall your current Python installation, then just use Anaconda. I don't normally use Windows but I can only guess. Maybe you didn't install `numpy` with the correct linkages. There are too many possibilities, and unless you really know what you are doing on Windows, it's going to be hard to figure out. The solution is to use a *pre-built* distribution like Anaconda or Enthought Canopy.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this not too long ago, I think script on windows is a little tricky. SciPy has directions to an installer on their webpage https://www.scipy.org/install.html. If you've installed python specifically for this project I would go and get anaconda. You can uninstall the python you have or just tell anaconda to replace the path during installation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys. I finally could solve the problem.
I don't know why, but I uninstall NumPy, SciPy and Scikit-Learn and install again using the binary files from here:

[link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

And it's work. All these libraries are working correctly.
Something was running wrong installing from pip.

Well, I think it's case closed. Thank you @Hopeful_O, @juanpa.arrivillaga, @abccd and @shadefc09 for the help.